# How make lodash _.replace all occurrence in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, lodash

How to replace each occurrence of a string pattern in a string by another string?

```
var text = "azertyazerty";
_.replace(text,"az","qu")
```

return `quertyazerty`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you have to use the RegExp with global option offered by lodash.

so just use

```
var text = "azertyazerty";
_.replace(text,new RegExp("az","g"),"qu")
```

to return `quertyquerty`

Comment: The "g" modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match)

Answer (score 51):

You can also do

```
var text = "azertyazerty";
var result = _.replace(text, /az/g, "qu");
```

Comment: This is essentially a code-only answer, which is not as useful as answers that offer some description.  You might mention that this is a "simpler" way to write a regular expression, but that you are in fact using a regular expression.

Answer (score 29):

I love lodash, but this is probably one of the few things that is easier without it.

```
var str = str.split(searchStr).join(replaceStr)
```

As a utility function with some error checking:

```
var replaceAll = function (str, search, replacement) {
  var newStr = ''
  if (_.isString(str)) { // maybe add a lodash test? Will not handle numbers now.
    newStr = str.split(search).join(replacement)
  }
  return newStr
}
```

For completeness, if you do really really want to use lodash, then to actually replace the text, assign the result to the variable.

```
var text = 'find me find me find me'
text = _.replace(text,new RegExp('find','g'),'replace')
```

References:
[How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Love it! Great solution without regexp. Because often searchStr can be provided by external input, in that case it might be not safe for regex (if it contains special characters), in that case this solution is brilliant and safe!

Answer (score 9):

Vanilla JS is fully capable of doing what you need without the help of lodash.

```
const text = "azertyazerty"
text.replace(new RegExp("az", "g"), "qu")
```

Comment: This is the most straight forward one in my opinion.

Comment: Not _fully_. This doesn't work with dynamic search strings which may have regex characters.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144788/8261